# Google App Engine NDB caching for loop local variable

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

```
# keyid is a string used for id in ndb keys. quest.reward=['1commonhead']
for keyid in quest.reward:
    item = ndb.Key('InventoryItem',keyid).get().toDict()
    rewards.append(item)
```

TypeError: Key id must be a string or a number; received {'gearType': '', 'level': 1L, 'color': 'lime', 'intelligence': 2L, 'damage': 2L, 'className': 'uncommonsword', 'grade': 'uncommon', 'subType': 'sword', 'prettyName': 'Uncommon sword of the Squirrel', 'type': 'weapon'}

I've tried passing kwds use_cache and use_memcache False but that didn't seem to work. 
this is my current fix. It feels messy to me. I'm I missing something about context caching?

```
rewards = []
for keyid in quest.reward:
    item = keyid
    if type(keyid) == str:
        item = ndb.Key('InventoryItem',keyid).get().toDict()
    rewards.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't realize what is in quest.reward.

The error says you can't use a dictionary as a key element, which is what you are trying to do.

The result of iterating over quest.reward is

`{'gearType': '', 'level': 1L, 'color': 'lime', 'intelligence': 2L, 'damage': 2L, 'className': 'uncommonsword', 'grade': 'uncommon', 'subType': 'sword', 'prettyName': 'Uncommon sword of the Squirrel', 'type': 'weapon'}`

This means quest.reward is a list of dictionaries (at least 1 dict)

I doubt caching has anything to do with this.  Where is `quest.reward` coming from and how is it defined.

Comment: Thanks Tim. quest.reward was stated in the first line of the post. quest.reward=['1commonhead']. It's a list of key ids. Not dicts. But somehow at random the items in the reward array are being converted / cached to a dict. I've read through the docs but can't seem to get a clear answer from them to why this is happening. quest.reward should always be a list of strings.

Comment: The evidence you provided doesn't support this statement.  Log quest.reward before the loop then log each keyid.  What you are suggesting I believe is not very likely. Appengine is just running python and everyone would be complaining.  Maybe there is some other code that is coming I not affect that you are not showing